# Looking for a quote from the Rambam's Moreh Nevuchim

Tags: sources-mekorot, rambam, moreh-nevuchim

I heard in a shiur that the Rambam in his Moreh Nevuchim writes that when one asks you a fundamental question about your religion, you will not be able to give a concise answer due to the fact that the questioner needs to understand many preliminary and introductory concepts in order to understand the answer.

If someone could perhaps find the source for this, either in the words of the Rambam or from another author, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Not sure, but the Introduction has a lot of these ideas: https://www.sefaria.org/Guide_for_the_Perplexed%2C_Introduction%2C_Prefatory_Remarks.7?lang=bi He explains why he cannot explain things fully.

Comment: @MichoelR Thank you so much for your feedback! At least the Rambam alludes to this idea, I appreciate your help.

Comment: Best wishes. The Moreh is hard to read!